# How to speak the line number?

Tags: expressions, numbers, ordinal-numbers

What is the most common way to identify a particular line of code in a talk or lecture?

1. On the seventeenth line of this code"
2. On the line seventeen of this code"
3. On the line number seventeen of this code"

Since we are identifying a particular line, the definite article should be needed, surely? If not, why not?

Comment: It's ***way*** more common to simply say it's ***on line 17** [of this code]*.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Assuming it's known I'm talking about code, I would simply say:

> On line seventeen.

If not, let's say I'm discussing a piece of software, I would qualify the sentence:

> On line seventeen of **the** code.

I would only use **this** if I were comparing one piece of code with another and visually indicating a particular piece of code.

I might phrase it as in your first sentence, but only in a specific, and uncommon, formal context.

That said, your second and third sentences are ungrammatical because neither should have **the** as their second word.

Comment: +1 for the final sentence -- the "the" in lines #2 and #3 of the question should definitely be removed.

Comment: But you're not answering the OP's bottommost question, which I believe is the _real_ question.

Comment: @MrLister the answer to the specific question of **why** could be improved by making a distinction between ordinal and cardinal numbers: as per the OPs examples, only the former requires an article. e.g. "on the second day of the trip..." (ordinal number)  vs "on day two of the trip..." (cardinal number).